# PostGIS: Does re-creating a spatial index after inserts or updates affect performance?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index

Creating a spatial index on a geometry field is [very important](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html). The docs also state that you should perform a VACUUM ANALYZE after large update operations. But is it ever necessary to drop an existing spatial index and recreate one after significant changes to a geometry field in a table?

Comment: At least there is usually no need to drop index because you can use reindex https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html. I am not sure if reindex is needed if VACUUM FULL is used https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html. The older documentation has mentioned that indexes get rebuild by the same. Perhaps you would get better answers from the db-admin site.

Comment: There can be speed advantages to dropping the index before large inserts and then reindexing, but otherwise I wouldn't see a need to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im assuming your talking about the doco here

https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html

I would probably research on general SQL DB's indexes, and under what circumstances to rebuild them.

Inserting/modifying data, will automatically build the index to include that new data. There might be some circumstances which you would consider 'significant' changes, which I would personally drop an index and recreate from scratch. These are

- Changes in geometry type for a record (point to a line geometry)
- Changes to the geometry field name (geom to geometry)
- Significant changes to the complexity of the data (eg: Neat polygons of state boundaries becoming overlapping many-vertixed donutted messes.

The above changes render the existing spatial index a bit redundant. PostGIS may automatically recreate it under some circumstances anyways (can't remember).

Comparatively, a large number of DB transactions (ie? simply inserting a large number of new records) may cause DB corruption, which then buggers up the index, but this is rare. If you have a DB which requires to be highly available, then your procedure for modifying data should be robust enough to minimize corruption. This may include a reindex procedure.

Some more info here as well:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219917/postgres-do-indexes-automatically-reindex-new-data